# What are some typical use-cases for machine learning models with "moderate" predictive performance

Tags: machine-learning

For example, say you have a classifier with an AUC of 0.75 (not good but not bad).  Are there any typical uses cases where predictive performance does not have to be very good?

Comment: It's useful in situations where your previous means of classification had an AUC less than 0.75. Gauging your classifier's performance might be better done with a notion of risk, though.

Comment: If AUC 0.75 adds more value than the other AUCs that you’ve tried, then this model is better than any alternative.